# How to upload large file from android to webserver

Tags: android

I want to upload images and videos to web server in chunks
But after uploading a chunk i have to again call for outputstream to transfer next chunk.Is there is any way that i have to call for outstream only for once.If not then why it is neccassary to call for outputstream each time after uploading a chunk.
**my code current code is**

```
 header('Content-type:bitmap;charset=utf-8');
 $super_parent_dir=$_POST["spd"];//super parent dic
 $parent_dir=$_POST["pd"];//parent dic
 $child_dir=$_POST["cd"];//super_child dic
 $host_no=$_POST["queue_num"];//child_dic
 $image_name=$_POST["image_name"];//file

$spd_path=$super_parent_dir;
$pd_path=$spd_path."/".$parent_dir;
$ch_path=$pd_path."/".$child_dir;
$f_folder=$ch_path."/".$host_no;

if(!is_dir($f_folder))
mkdir($f_folder, 0777);//echo $f_folder;

if(isset($_POST["Image_data"])){

$econded_string=$_POST["Image_data"];   
$decode_string=base64_decode($econded_string);
$path=$f_folder.'/'.$image_name;
$file=fopen($path,'a');
$is_written=fwrite($file,$decode_string);
fclose($file);

if($is_written>0){
    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imgae_db");
    $query="insert into photos values('','$path','$image_name')";
    $result=    mysqli_query($connection,$query);

}}
```

public class Media_uploader extends AsyncTask {

```
private String image_file;
public Media_uploader(File image){
    this.image_file= String.valueOf(image);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);

    byte[] array=stream.toByteArray();
    String a= Base64.encodeToString(array,Base64.DEFAULT);


    try {
        URL url=new URL("http://192.168.1.1**/db_mager/Medaia_Downloader.php");
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream stream1=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream1,"UTF-8"));

        String data= URLEncoder.encode("spd","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Session_Data.getMyDatabase(),"UTF-8")+"&"+
                     URLEncoder.encode("pd","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Session_Data.getMyCity(),"UTF-8")+"&"+
                     URLEncoder.encode("cd","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(Session_Data.getMyID(),"UTF-8")+"&"+
                     URLEncoder.encode("queue_num","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(Session_Data.getActivity_Record()),"UTF-8")+"&"+
                     URLEncoder.encode("image_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(image_file,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                     URLEncoder.encode("Image_data","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(a,"UTF-8");

        bufferedWriter.write(data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        stream1.close();

        InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: heard about multipart data upload?

Comment: Yes try with multipart better option

Comment: Please provide the code you have on this so far. Visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use this library:

https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service

Answer (score 0):

This code is an example of using a multipart upload from Android to a server - there are different libraries that will support this also so it would be worth you doing some research to decide which is best for you but the below is tested and works.

```js
public class VideoUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    /* This Class is an AsynchTask to upload a video to a server on a background thread
     * 
     */

    private VideoUploadTaskListener thisTaskListener;
    private String serverURL;
    private String videoPath;

    public VideoUploadTask(VideoUploadTaskListener ourListener) {
        //Constructor
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","constructor");

        //Set the listener
        thisTaskListener = ourListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Upload the video in the background
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask","doInBackground");

        //Get the Server URL and the local video path from the parameters
        if (params.length == 2) {
            serverURL = params[0];
            videoPath = params[1];
        } else {
            //One or all of the params are not present - log an error and return
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","One or all of the params are not present");
            return -1;
        }


        //Create a new Multipart HTTP request to upload the video
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverURL);

        //Create a Multipart entity and add the parts to it
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Building the request for file: " + videoPath);
            FileBody filebodyVideo = new FileBody(new File(videoPath));
            StringBody title = new StringBody("Filename:" + videoPath);
            StringBody description = new StringBody("test Video");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("videoFile", filebodyVideo);
            reqEntity.addPart("title", title);
            reqEntity.addPart("description", description);
            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","UnsupportedEncodingException error when setting StringBody for title or description");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        //Send the request to the server
        HttpResponse serverResponse = null;
        try {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Sending the Request");
            serverResponse = httpclient.execute( httppost );
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ClientProtocolException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Log the error
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Check the response code
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","Checking the response code");
        if (serverResponse != null) {
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","ServerRespone" + serverResponse.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity responseEntity = serverResponse.getEntity( );
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                //log the response code and consume the content
                Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","responseEntity is not null");
                try {
                    responseEntity.consumeContent( );
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Log the (further...) error...
                    Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","IOexception consuming content");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        } else {
            //Log that response code was null
            Log.d("VideoUploadTask doInBackground","serverResponse = null");
            return -1;
        }

        //Shut down the connection manager
        httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( ); 
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //Check the return code and update the listener
        Log.d("VideoUploadTask onPostExecute","updating listener after execution");
        thisTaskListener.onUploadFinished(result);
    }

}
```